# SVN discover when a code was inserted at a given file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using SVN for version control, is it possible to discover when a specific code was inserted at a given file?

Can i give to SVN, or using tortoiseSVN, a piece of code and a file and SVN discover when that code was first inserted ?

Comment: The feature is called [blame](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-blame.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Patrick suggested, the feature you are looking for is [Blame](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html) (also called Praise or Annotate). Don't miss related SVNBook sections:

- [Displaying line-by-line change attribution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.browsing.annotate)
- [`svn blame` command-line reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html)

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong, i see that using blame, is a matter of guessing between a range of revisions, to see who inserted a specific line. This is what i have done to find in wich revision a specific code line appears.